# Problema al integrar la funcion OnClickListener a mi RecyclerView

Tags: recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, onclicklistener

estoy siguiendo un tutorial para agregarle una opción de pulsar a mi RecyclerView y que me lleve a otra Activity. hasta ahora todo bien me pero mi problema es cuando el programa no me compila culpa de un error que no puedo solucionar

```
package com.example.atipicoapp

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter(private val platoList : ArrayList<Plato>,
                private val itemClickListener: OnPlatoClickListener
                ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    interface OnPlatoClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(nombre: String)
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        return MyViewHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

            val plato : Plato = platoList[position]
            holder.platoName.text = plato.platoName
            holder.platoDescription.text = plato.platoDescription
            holder.platoPrecio.text = plato.platoPrecio.toString()
            holder.platoCantidad.text = plato.platoCantidad.toString()

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return platoList.size

    }

    public class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

            override fun bind(item: Plato, position: Int){

                itemView.setOnClickListener( OnPlatoClickListener.onItemClick(item.nombre))

            }

        val platoName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoNombre)
        val platoDescription : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoDescripcion)
        val platoPrecio : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoPrecio)
        val platoCantidad : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoCant)

    }
}
```

Este es mi `MyAdapter` el problema esta en la fila 48. sospecho que algo tiene que ver la función `override fun bind` porque la tuve que agregar para el tutorial.

El RecyclerView recibe todo la información desde Firebase Firestore.

El error que me sale al Compilar es `'bind' overrides nothing`. Me salen otros errores como: `Unresolved reference: onItemClick` que esta en la misma funcion

Agradezco su ayuda, si necesitan que pase mas de código para ver mi error estaré leyendo

Comment: " mi problema es cuando el programa no me compila culpa de un error que no puedo solucionar" Cual es el error? que error se muestra en el LogCat? es importante especificar los errores., saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, ya actualice la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la clase `MyViewHolder` no debes implementar ningún método, solo debes obtener las referencias de las vistas que definidas en el layout definido en `onCreateViewHolder()` , que en este caso es `list_item.xml`.

```
 public class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

       /* override fun bind(item: Plato, position: Int){   
                itemView.setOnClickListener( OnPlatoClickListener.onItemClick(item.nombre))    
            }*/

        val platoName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoNombre)
        val platoDescription : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoDescripcion)
        val platoPrecio : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoPrecio)
        val platoCantidad : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoCant)

    }
```

en el método `onCreateViewHolder()` debes retornar el ViewHolder:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
    //val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
    val vh: MyViewHolder =
            MyViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))

    return vh

}
```

y dentro de `onBindViewHolder()` puedes modificar las propiedades de los elementos en el layout `list_item.xml`:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

            val plato : Plato = platoList[position]
            holder.platoName.text = plato.platoName
            holder.platoDescription.text = plato.platoDescription
            holder.platoPrecio.text = plato.platoPrecio.toString()
            holder.platoCantidad.text = plato.platoCantidad.toString()

    }
```

---

Para asignar el `clicklistener`, lo puedes realizar dentro de `onCreateViewHolder()` a una de las vistas en el layout, por ejemplo:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {

    val vh: MyViewHolder =
            MyViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))

    //Asigna listener.
    vh.platoCantidad.setOnClickListener( View.OnClickListener { v: View ->

            //Acción que realizará el clic            

        })

    return vh

}
```

Comment: Esta bien, ahora puedo compilar mi aplicacion, pero no queda nada de la funcion setOnClickListener. ¿Como puedo implementarla correctamente para poder hacer click en mi Item?

Comment: @LucasAndresEscudero Puedes realizarlo en onCreateViewHolder() revisa el ejemplo que agregué.

Comment: Ya vi muchas gracias!!, Ahora me fijare en hacer el intent para cambiar de activity.

Comment: No encuentro todavia como poner un Intent en la funcion que me dijiste. ¿Me podrias ayudar? Te lo agradeceria